# How do you implement IComparable to sort an array of a custom type?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, icomparable

I wrote a program for my C# class and need to figure out how to implement IComparable to be able to sort an array of a custom type. It compiles with no errors, but throws an exception when run:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.

I've searched for hours to find a solution to no avail. There's tons of info on the subject, but I'm probably just overthinking it. I'll post the program and if someone could point me in the right direction with an explanation I'd be eternally grateful as the deadline for this is rapidly approaching.
P.S. This is my first time posting here so please be gentle when criticizing my shortcomings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HighScores4
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {         
         string playerInitials;
         int playerScore;

         const int NUM_PLAYERS = 10;

         Player[] stats = new Player[NUM_PLAYERS];         

         for (int index = 0; index < NUM_PLAYERS; index++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your initials: ");
            playerInitials = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your score: ");
            playerScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            stats[index] = new Player(playerScore, playerInitials);            
         }

         Array.Sort(stats);   **// Exception thrown here**
         Array.Reverse(stats);

         for (int index = 0; index < NUM_PLAYERS; index++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(stats[index].ToString());
         }

#if DEBUG
         Console.ReadKey();
#endif 

      } 
   }

   public class Player 
   {      
      public string Initials { get; set; }
      public int Score { get; set; }

      public Player(int score, string initials)
      {
         Initials = initials;
         Score = Score;
      } 

      public override string ToString()
      {
         return string.Format("{0, 3}, {1, 7}", Score, Initials);
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: `Player` needs to implement `IComparable`. Not sure what the question is though. The answer to the question in the title is: You implement IComparable.

Comment: In order for your solution to work you need to implement IComparable for the Player class. For this, you need to know how do you want to sort players at first. E.g. you can sort by initials or score.

Answer (score 3):

The exception message is perfectly clear.

```
must implement IComparable
```

It means you have to implement `IComparable` for your `Player` class.

```
public class Player : IComparable<Player>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I guess I should have mentioned that I need to sort the array by scores, keeping the initials in sync with them.

Comment: He should implement `IComparable<Player>`, not `IComparable`. **Addition:** Alternatively, he could use another overload of `Array.Sort` that takes in an extra parameter specifying how to compare players.

Comment: How would it be inserted into the body of the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambda expression to create `IComparer<Player>` (with `Comparer<Type>.Create`) and pass it in `Array.Sort(array, comparer)` argument. Code snippet:

```
Comparer<Player> scoreComparer =
    Comparer<Player>.Create((first, second) => first.Score.CompareTo(second.Score));

Array.Sort(tab, scoreComparer);
```