# InvalidOperationException when try to sort an array of objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have this class on my c# console application

```
public class Person 
{
    public Person(int id , string l, string f)
    {
            FirstName = f;
            LastName = l;
            Id = id;
    }

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

In my Main method I have the following code:

```
 public  static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person[] p = new Person[3];

            p[0] = new Person(8,"John", "Doe");
            p[1] = new Person(9,"Adam", "Cas");
            p[2] = new Person(1,"Oliver", "Anderson");

            Array.Sort(p); // this doesn't work, i get InvalidOperationException
      }
```

If it is array of simple types like string , int,..etc i can easily use `Array.Sort(myarray)` and then it will be sorted.But when i use `Array.Sort(p)` i get an exception (`InvalidOperationException`).

Indeed this is expected exception as documentation on [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_) says

> InvalidOperationException
>   One or more elements in array do not implement the `IComparable` interface.

Unfortunately all samples show how to implement `IComparer` for string while I need to be able to sort by a string *property* of the object ( Id, FirstName, LastName ). And there is no sample of `IComparable` which my objects presumably need to imlement.

Here is a sample from the documentation:

```
public class ReverseComparer : IComparer
{
   // Call CaseInsensitiveComparer.Compare with the parameters reversed.
   public int Compare(Object x, Object y)
   {
       return (new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(y, x );
   }
}
```

There are indeed samples of `IComparer` (like [Using IComparer for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336416/using-icomparer-for-sorting)) but they show `IComparer<T>`... There is also sample of `IComparable` is corresponding documentation [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netcore-3.1) but that one is for temperature with non-string properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you implement IComparable to sort an array of a custom type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580822/how-do-you-implement-icomparable-to-sort-an-array-of-a-custom-type)

Comment: @devNull to sort i want to choose one of my properties to sort, either Id, or FirstName, or LastName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error makes sense because you are trying to sort a complex object, how do you compare an object to another object, what you can do is use an `IComparable <T>` comparison interface to be able to compare two objects as shown in the code below:

```
public  static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Person[] p = new Person[3];

    p[0] = new Person(8,"John", "Doe");
    p[1] = new Person(9,"Adam", "Cas");
    p[2] = new Person(1,"Oliver", "Anderson");

    Array.Sort(p,new Comparison<Person>((i1,i2)=> i1.Id.CompareTo(i2.Id)));   
}
```

what you can do also is to use Linq :

```
public  static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Person[] p = new Person[3];

    p[0] = new Person(8,"John", "Doe");
    p[1] = new Person(9,"Adam", "Cas");
    p[2] = new Person(1,"Oliver", "Anderson");

    var result = p.OrderBy(e => e.Id)
                 .ToArray(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, but i still seek a specific answer with hard coding to the mechanisms of comparing. It is an assignment needs to be solved with more details as my instructor requires.

Comment: Our instructor wants us to create a new class eg:PersonComparer:IComparer<Person> with a constructor that receives a specific string property and then override the method Compare(Person x, Person y) with switch - case to determine the property which is going to be used on sorting. To perform sorting in the main method you will type Array.Sort(p, new PersonComparer("LastName")); That is what he did and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Person` implement `IComparable<Person>`, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    private int _id;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public Person(int id, string l, string f)
    {
        _firstName = f;
        _lastName = l;
        _id = id;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return this.LastName.CompareTo(other.LastName);
    }
}
```

Then change the logic in `CompareTo` for whatever you want to compare. In this case, it does `LastName`, but you could also change that to `ID` or `FirstName`.

BTW, it looks like you have your first and last names backwards when instantiating and assigning `Person` to the `p` array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your solution is OK, but it just works for LastName, I want to give more options to be chosen on sorting, Like sorting by any one of my properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=netframework-4.8) delegate to sort the `Person` array by any property of this class

```cs
Comparison<Person> comparison = (x, y) => x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
Array.Sort(p, comparison);
```

Another (and more generic) way is to write an extension method for `Person[]` array and pass a `Func<Person, TValue>` selector to get a value, used for comparison during sort

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static void SortExt<TValue>(this Person[] array, Func<Person, TValue> selector)
    {
        var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
        Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
    }
}
```

Example of the usage

```cs
p.SortExt(person => person.FirstName); //or p.SortExt(person => person.LastName);
```